# How to save OAuth Access Token in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, katana

I have implemented simple OAuth server with Katana using following steps:

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/simple-oauth-server-implementing-a-simple-oauth-server-with-katana-oauth-authorization-server-components-part-1

I need to log each and every API Usage so when user access any API, I have to save the generated access token and other information in database.

In **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** method, Is there any way to get generated access token or is there any event in **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider** where I could get it?

Comment: Did you get any resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a way to get the token in the **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** method.  However, if you override the **TokenEndpointResponse** method, you can grab the access token there.  It may be a little late in the pipeline for your purposes, but it's there.